# Can you store a Shatter spell in a magic mouth?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The Magic Mouth spell allows the caster to store a message within an object. One of my players asked me to define a message as he wanted to store a captured monster's roar as evidence, so I dictated that the spell could hold and recite any audible noise provided it was not more than 25 distinct noises and did not exceed the 10-minute mark as specified in the spell. This seemed reasonable to me until he asked to store a shatter spell. Shatter is a spell that when cast emits "A sudden loud ringing noise" that will damage nearby creatures and objects. Because the effects of the spell are entirely vocal, could you store a shatter spell inside a magic mouth, and if not, to what extent can you store no-traditional messages such as monster noises and other audible cues that don't specifically convey any message?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### *Magic mouth* cannot be used to record *anything* except for the sound of your own voice speaking words.

*Magic mouth* defines "message" for us:

> speak the message, which *must be 25 words or less*

Non-descript noises, grunts, growls, sonic booms, and the sound of a *shatter* spell are not words, so are not eligible for storage in a *magic mouth*.

Further, *magic mouth* states:

> *You* implant a message within an object in range, [...] speak the message [...]
>
> [...] a magical mouth appears on the object and recites the message in *your voice* and at the *same volume you spoke*.

*Magic mouth* cannot be used to record *anything* except for the sound of your own voice speaking words, and doesn't produce any sound except the sound of your own voice, speaking those words, exactly as you recited them when you cast the spell.

Comment: This is correct. Like, as a DM, I'd allow a *magic mouth* to record all your ums and uhs and other vocalized non-word sounds, but it still has to be *you* saying it.

Comment: It may be useful to remember that it reproduces those words as you spoke them. So if you sing those words then magic mouth also sings those words.